# Grouping data from csv file

Tags: python, csv

I have data in the following format in csv file:

```
col1       col2    col3    col4
----       ----    ----    ----
 a          xy      11      66
 a          xz      11      66
 b          zz      99      33
 b          za      99      33
```

I would like to add them to a list in the following format(order of inner elements does not matter):

```
 list1 = [["a",["xy","xz"],11,66],["b",["zz","za"],99,33]]
```

I've tried so far:

```
with open(assignment_data_set) as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')

    for row in csv_reader:
        protein[row[0]].append(row[8])
        protein[row[0]].append(row[5])
        protein[row[0]].append(row[1])
```

Result:

```
['66', 'xy', '11', '66', 'xz', '11']
```

Column 2 is not grouped and multiple entries for column 3.

Also tried:

```
with open(assignment_data_set) as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')

    for row in csv_reader:
        protein[row[0]].append(row[8])
    
    for row in csv_reader:
        protein[row[0]].append(row[5])
        protein[row[0]].append(row[1])
```

Result:

```
['66', '66']
```

Only duplicated column 3.

Also tried:

```
with open(assignment_data_set) as csv_file:
csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')

for row in csv_reader:
    protein[row[0]] = [row[0],row[8],row[1]]
    protein[row[0]].append(row[5])
```

Result:

```
['a', '66', '11', 'xy']
```

'xy' entry is missing from col2-row2, it should be ['a', '66', '11', ['xy','xz']]

How can I add grouped 'col2' to 'col1' row and also add 'col3' and 'col4; to the same row?

Comment: Your example data (3 columns) changes from the abstract version at the beginning to concrete data (9? columns) your using in your program. Will you either add a fragment of the real data that captures the problem, or change your example to use the sample data?

Comment: Also, in your sample data, the data in column 3 happens to match for column 1. How do you go from two samples of 12 and 89 to one each?

Comment: Hi Zach, thanks for looking into it. Yes, the data for col1 and col3 always matches, so I don't need duplicates for that. Only col2 can have different entries, but it needs to be mapped to col1, like this: list1 = [["a",["xy","xz"],12],["b",["zz","za"],89]]

Comment: I modified the question, I hope it's better now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two issues with the code you've shared, and they both have to do with the `protein` data structure you've created.

1. For each new protein, you need to initialize that protein's name in your protein dict. The initialized value will be a list with an empty list and the two integers from col3 and col4:

   ```py
   protein[col1] = [[], col3, col4]
   ```

   col2 will be appended to the empty list in a separate step...
2. Then you can append col2 to the first element in the *value* for col1, in a separate step:

   ```py
   protein[col1][0].append(col2)
   ```

Here's how that looks so far:

```py
import csv

protein_builder = {}  # {key: [[str], int, int]}

with open("input.csv", newline="") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)

    for row in reader:
        col1 = row[0]
        col2 = row[1]
        col3 = int(row[2])  # convert to int
        col4 = int(row[3])

        if col1 not in protein_builder:
            protein_builder[col1] = [[], col3, col4]

        protein_builder[col1][0].append(col2)

print(protein_builder)
```

I ran that on your sample data and got:

```py
{'a': [['xy', 'xz'], 11, 66], 'b': [['zz', 'za'], 99, 33]}
```

This isn't the final data structure you're looking for. We need one more step to take each protein name (the key in the dict) and join with its value into a single list, then append that to a list of all protein name/values:

```py
protein_final = []

for k, v in protein_builder.items():
    final_row = [k] + v  # v is [[str], int, int]
    protein_final.append(final_row)

print(protein_final)
```

I ran that and got:

```py
[['a', ['xy', 'xz'], 11, 66], ['b', ['zz', 'za'], 99, 33]]
```

Comment: Million thanks, Zach!